# How to update a key for all my objects that are in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this array on input :

```
const categories = [ 
  { id: 9, name: 'General Knowledge' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Entertainment: Books' },
  { id: 11, name: 'Entertainment: Film' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Entertainment: Music' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Entertainment: Musicals & Theatres' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Entertainment: Television' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Entertainment: Video Games' },
  { id: 16, name: 'Entertainment: Board Games' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Science & Nature' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Science: Computers' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Science: Mathematics' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Mythology' },
  { id: 21, name: 'Sports' },
  { id: 22, name: 'Geography' },
  { id: 23, name: 'History' },
  { id: 24, name: 'Politics' },
  { id: 25, name: 'Art' },
  { id: 26, name: 'Celebrities' },
  { id: 27, name: 'Animals' },
  { id: 28, name: 'Vehicles' },
  { id: 29, name: 'Entertainment: Comics' },
  { id: 30, name: 'Science: Gadgets' },
  { id: 31, name: 'Entertainment: Japanese Anime & Manga' },
  { id: 32, name: 'Entertainment: Cartoon & Animations' } 
]
```

I need to translate all the keys name of my objects.
For that, I use the google translation API.

here is the code :

```
googleTranslate.translate(categories.map(i => i.name), 'en', 'fr', function(err, translations) {
     console.log(translations.map(tr => tr.translatedText))
})
```

So the result is :

```
[ 'Culture générale',
  'Divertissement: livres',
  'Divertissement: Film',
  'Divertissement: Musique',
  'Divertissement: comédies musicales et théâtres',
  'Divertissement: Télévision',
  'Divertissement: jeux vidéo',
  'Divertissement: jeux de société',
  'Science et nature',
  'Science: Informatique',
  'Science: Mathématiques',
  'Mythologie',
  'Des sports',
  'La géographie',
  'L\'histoire',
  'Politique',
  'Art',
  'Célébrités',
  'Animaux',
  'Véhicules',
  'Divertissement: BD',
  'Science: Gadgets',
  'Divertissement: anime et manga japonais',
  'Divertissement: dessin animé et animations' ]
```

But I would like to keep the structure of the first array. Only update the keys name with the translations.

Output :

```
const categories = [ 
  { id: 9, name: 'Culture générale' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Divertissement: livres' },
  { id: 11, name: 'Divertissement: Film' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Divertissement: Musique' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Divertissement: comédies musicales et théâtres' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Divertissement: Télévision' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Divertissement: jeux vidéo' },
  { id: 16, name: 'Divertissement: jeux de société' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Science et nature' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Science: Informatique' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Science: Mathématiques' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Mythologie' },
  { id: 21, name: 'Des sports' },
  { id: 22, name: 'La géographie' },
  { id: 23, name: 'L\'histoire' },
  { id: 24, name: 'Politique' },
  { id: 25, name: 'Art' },
  { id: 26, name: 'Célébrités' },
  { id: 27, name: 'Animaux' },
  { id: 28, name: 'Véhicules' },
  { id: 29, name: 'Divertissement: BD' },
  { id: 30, name: 'Science: Gadgets' },
  { id: 31, name: 'Divertissement: anime et manga japonais' },
  { id: 32, name: 'Divertissement: dessin animé et animations' } 
]
```

I have not found how to do it yet.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: So what should output look like?

Comment: Oh sorry ! I just updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
googleTranslate.translate(categories.map(i => i.name), 'en', 'fr', function(err, translations) {
     console.log(translations.map(tr => {
       id: tr.id, 
       name: tr.name 
     }
  ))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could recreate the old structure after the translation:

```
const categories [...];
const translatedCategories = new Array();

googleTranslate.translate(categories.map(i => i.name), 'en', 'fr', function(err, translations) {
    translations.forEach((tr, index) => {
        translatedCategories.push({
            id: categories[index].id,
            name: tr.translatedText
        });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just change the name of your categories, this should do the trick...

```
function replace(categories, result) {

      for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
          categories[i].name = result[i];          
      }

      return categories;
  }
```

have a look at the snippet, it's simple.

```js
const categories = [ 
    { id: 9, name: 'General Knowledge' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Entertainment: Books' },
    { id: 11, name: 'Entertainment: Film' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Entertainment: Music' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Entertainment: Musicals & Theatres' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Entertainment: Television' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Entertainment: Video Games' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Entertainment: Board Games' },
    { id: 17, name: 'Science & Nature' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Science: Computers' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Science: Mathematics' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Mythology' },
    { id: 21, name: 'Sports' },
    { id: 22, name: 'Geography' },
    { id: 23, name: 'History' },
    { id: 24, name: 'Politics' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Art' },
    { id: 26, name: 'Celebrities' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Animals' },
    { id: 28, name: 'Vehicles' },
    { id: 29, name: 'Entertainment: Comics' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Science: Gadgets' },
    { id: 31, name: 'Entertainment: Japanese Anime & Manga' },
    { id: 32, name: 'Entertainment: Cartoon & Animations' } 
  ]

const result = [ 'Culture générale',
  'Divertissement: livres',
  'Divertissement: Film',
  'Divertissement: Musique',
  'Divertissement: comédies musicales et théâtres',
  'Divertissement: Télévision',
  'Divertissement: jeux vidéo',
  'Divertissement: jeux de société',
  'Science et nature',
  'Science: Informatique',
  'Science: Mathématiques',
  'Mythologie',
  'Des sports',
  'La géographie',
  'L\'histoire',
  'Politique',
  'Art',
  'Célébrités',
  'Animaux',
  'Véhicules',
  'Divertissement: BD',
  'Science: Gadgets',
  'Divertissement: anime et manga japonais',
  'Divertissement: dessin animé et animations' ];

  let catNew = replace(categories, result);

  console.log(catNew);

  function replace(categories, result) {

      for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
          categories[i].name = result[i];          
      }

      return categories;
  }
```